# conflict with biblatex and custom class

Tags: biblatex

I am customizing `apa6e` for a large report. I need the functionality of `apa6e`'s `leavefloats` option. But when that option is passed to the class, `biblatex-apa` doesn't work, giving me an error about the argument of `\MakeLowercase` having an extra `}`.

By removing `leavefloats`, everything works perfectly. I can't figure out why exactly from reading the code, I'd appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

A latex example:

```
\documentclass[leavefloats]{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\bibliography{books}
\title{Test}
\shorttitle{Test}
\author{Johnny B. Good}
\authornote{\ldots}
\abstract{\ldots}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  This is my example \parencite{good}.
  \newpage
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The accompanying bib file:

```
@Book{good,
      author={Johnny B. Good},
      title={My great book},
      publisher={Good Publishing},
      year={1910}
}
```

Comment: A MWE example would be useful.

Comment: The command `authornotes` is undefined. The correct one is `authornote`. Avoid the command `\bibliography` instead use `\addbibresource{books.bib}`. With this modification your example works without any errors.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks! this is exactly what I needed. If you can add it as an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: @ravl1084: Done ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>In relation to the comments I switch my comment to an answer</sub>

The error in your code based on the command `\authonotes`. This command is undefined. The correct one is `\authornote` (without "s").

Next thing. Please use `\addbibresource` instead of `\bibliography`. The manual of `biblatex` explains the differences and the advantages of `\addbibresource`. However `\addbibresource` expect the filename with the extension.

```
\addbibresource{books.bib}
```